# Understanding the Electronic Behavior of a Band Structure with Small Band Crossing

Tags: band-structure, density-of-states

I would like to extend this [question](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/11908/1554) that I have asked before regarding semi-metallic characterisitc of a bandstructure.

How can we describe the electronic behavior of a band structure in the attached figure, where only one band from the unoccupied states is slightly crossing the Fermi level, while no crossing has been observed from the occupied states?

conisdering the density of states (DOS) at the Fermi level (refer to the attached figure), it is found to be very low. with such observations, can we classify this material as a metal, a semi-metal, or a some special type of topological material? What additional analyses or considerations are necessary to fully understand the electronic behavior in this scenario?
[image]
I have to mention that the Figures of the bandstructure and DOS belongs to a tubular structure of WTe2 which is well known to be a type-II Weyl semimetal in its bulk 1T'-distorted phase, and also theoretically predicted to be a 2D topological insulator.